# Angular/WebApp design

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I'm currently creating a web app in Angular (beginner) and I'm a little deep into it. I potentially want to alter my design and get input on other possible designs of my app. There are two routes, first route is the main page which shows a table full of links. When I click on one of these links, it will send me to my second route (I pass in key data to the URLs for the second route from the first one). The second route is a tabulated view of some information.

One reason I wanted to alter the design was so I could only have one route (with tabs). The first tab will show my table full of links (first route) and the rest of the tabs will show the information  (second route) therefore compiling it into one route. Is it possible to click on the link (first route) and it will lead to me to the next tab with key information I can use to populate that tab or is it better to separate it out?

example (current design):

first route (table):

person_1, person2, person3

person_4, person5, person6

second route (pretend I clicked person1):

tab, tab, tab. Information about that person in each tab (Using parameters passed in through url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show something in a different tab you could just hide the tab using jquery or ng-hide. 
So when the link is clicked instead of navigating to another route simply call a function to show the hidden tab after loading the info for that tab

Comment: instead of hiding the tab, is it possible to just open that tab up when I click the link using a function?

Comment: Yeah you can do that but that will mean a user can view that tab without clicking on the link.... Which you might not want

Comment: yes true but I'm populating that data based off the clicked link. One more thing: When I click the link, can I pass data inside the URL and then use that data inside the new tab?

Comment: Since its on the same page you don't need to pass data inside a url. Simply store the data in a variable attached to $scope and display the contents of the variable in the tab

Comment: ahhh it just clicked. Thanks!